# Problem either in allocation or handling array of pointer to struct

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

I have a problem (or maybe a few)
I'm trying to struggle with pointers to pointers to struct, and I'm not understanding whether is a problem of memory allocation, or a problem of passing the right things to my function.
Here's (part of) the code

```
typedef struct Corsa {
  char codice[15];
  char partenza[15];
  char destinazione[15];
  int giorno, mese, anno, oraP, minP, oraA, minA, ritardo;
} corsa;

corsa** allocaStructArray(int numStruct);
void leggiEStampaStruct(FILE *fp, corsa **pntToCorsa, int numR);

// ..main and other functs..

corsa** allocaStructArray(int numStruct) //numStruct is the number of 'rows'
{
  corsa **pointerToStructCorsa;
  pointerToStructCorsa = malloc(numStruct * sizeof(corsa));

  if (pointerToStructCorsa == NULL)
    printf("\nErrore di allocazione.\n");

  return pointerToStructCorsa;
}

void leggiEStampaStruct(FILE *fp, corsa **pntToCorsa, int numR) {
  int i;
  fclose(fp);
  fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
  if (fp == NULL)
    exit(232);

  for (i = 0; i < numR; i++) {
    fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s %d/%d/%d %d.%d %d.%d %d", pntToCorsa[i]->codice,
        pntToCorsa[i]->partenza, pntToCorsa[i]->destinazione,
        &pntToCorsa[i]->giorno, &pntToCorsa[i]->mese, &pntToCorsa[i]->anno,
        &pntToCorsa[i]->oraP, &pntToCorsa[i]->minP, &pntToCorsa[i]->oraA,
        &pntToCorsa[i]->minA, &pntToCorsa[i]->ritardo);

  }

  for (i = 0; i < numR; i++) {
    printf("\n%s %s %s %d/%d/%d %d.%d %d.%d %d\n", pntToCorsa[i]->codice,
        pntToCorsa[i]->partenza, pntToCorsa[i]->destinazione,
        pntToCorsa[i]->giorno, pntToCorsa[i]->mese, pntToCorsa[i]->anno,
        pntToCorsa[i]->oraP, pntToCorsa[i]->minP, pntToCorsa[i]->oraA,
        pntToCorsa[i]->minA, pntToCorsa[i]->ritardo);
  }

  return;
}
```

Another thing that I don't like is that I can't check manually if everything is at its place.

Like if it was a normal matrix, I could have checked if the values were placed in the right spots but with pointers I literally can't and that doesn't help finding the problem.

Do you guys have some tips on this other problem?

Comment: I think `allocaStructArray` should just return `corsa*` instead of `corsa**`.

Comment: Your title says array of pointers to struct but you only allocate memory for an array of structs, no pointers to structs. If you don't have pointers, the comment of kiner_shah is correct. Just drop one `*` from that return type. And also inside that function.

Comment: During printing you have the same problem. `pntToCorsa[i]` is allocated as a struct, not a pointer. You also do not show any code that would allocate some memory for such a pointer to point at.  Therefore it should be `pntToCorsa[i].codice` instead of `pntToCorsa[i]->codice`.

Comment: You did not tell us what your problem is at all. Using the wrong type for memory allocation will result in waste of memory but not cause any trouble as your struct is larger than a single pointer. Therefore what problem does "and that doesn't help finding the problem" address?

Comment: Do you allocate any memory for `pntToCorsa[i]` anywhere in the code you don't show?

Answer (score 0):

At least these problems

**No width in `fscanf()`**

Do not use `"%s"` without a width limit in `fscanf()`.  Use `"%14s %14s %14s ...`  as each points to an array of 15.

**Check input result**

Check the return value.  Add a test to see if the 11 specifiers all parsed.

```
 if (fscanf(....) != 11) Handle_Error();
```

**Allocation error**

Wrong type in `sizeof`.

Avoid this problem by sizing to the refenced object and **not** the type.  Easier to code right, review and maintain.  Also, unclear what OP wants to do when `numStruct < 0`, so added a test.

```
// Wrong size                                v-----------v 
// pointerToStructCorsa = malloc(numStruct * sizeof(corsa));
if (numStruct >= 0) {
  //                            v--------------------------v Right size for referenced object. 
  pointerToStructCorsa = malloc(sizeof *pointerToStructCorsa * numStruct);
  ...
```

Comment: That's a very good answer, thank you very much :)

Comment: @JackBet For more, it would have been better had you posted a [mcve].